# How would you create a basic loop using User input that breaks when the user enters a word to end the program?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Im looking to create an empty array that is updated forever via a loop until the user enters "stop". I really cannot figure out how to do it.

```
var array = [];

while (true) {
  array = prompt("Say something?");
  if (array) == "stop" {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Shall `prompt` value assign to an array?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to change `var array = [];` to `var array;`,make sure the variable `array` is not a array

```js
var array;

while (true) {
  array = prompt("Say something?");
  if(array == "stop") {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: not a downvoter but you haven't explained anything to OP. An answer like that allows people to copy paste without understanding anything. Beside, `var array = []` isn't the problem here

Answer (score 0):

1. Your syntax for `if` is incorrect
2. You are not updating the array instead overwriting it with the latest prompt

```js
const array = [];

while (true) {
  const val = prompt("Say something?");
  if (val == "stop") {
    break;
  }
  array.push(val);
}
```